# How to use delete[] in destructor

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I have the following files for implementing a `Bucket` class. However I can't destroy the `_str` member in the destructor of the `Bucket`s produced by the `operator+`. The error that I get is:

> heap corruption detected after normal block...CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

The problem always occurs after the addition of the two `Bucket` objects, however I've checked during the debugging that the produced string is correct as well as the length.

Also, how can I access the `_len` attribute in the `operator>>` function in order to assign a new value?

Header File:

```
class Bucket
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bucket& c);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Bucket& c);
public:
    Bucket();
    Bucket(const String& str);
    Bucket(const char* str);
    ~Bucket();
    const Bucket operator+(const Bucket& s) const;
    const Bucket operator+(const char* s) const;
    const Bucket& operator=(const char* c);
    const bool operator==(const char* str);
private:
    char* _str;
    int _len;
};
```

Source File:

```
Bucket::Bucket() {
    _len = 0;
    _str = new char[_len];
}

Bucket::Bucket(const Bucket& myBucket) {
    _len = myBucket._len;
    _str = new char[_len + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++)
        _str[i] = myBucket._str[i];
    _str[_len] = '\0';
}

Bucket::Bucket(const char* str) {
    _len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) _len++;
    
    _str = new char[_len + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++)
        _str[i] = str[i];
    _str[_len] = '\0';
}

Bucket::~Bucket() {
    if (_len > 0) delete[] _str;
}

const Bucket Bucket::operator+(const Bucket& myBucket) const {
    String tempBucket;
    tempBucket._str = strcat(this->_str, myBucket._str);
    int len = 0;
    
    while (tempBucket._str[len] != '\0') len++;
    tempBucket._str[len] = '\0';
    tempBucket._len = len;
    return tempBucket;
}

const Bucket Bucket::operator+(const char* str) const {
    Bucket tempBucket;
    
    int len = 0;

    tempBucket._len = this->_len;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) tempBucket._len++;

    tempBucket._str = strcat(tempBucket._str, str);

    tempBucket._str[len] = '\0';
    tempBucket._len = len;
    return tempBucket;
}

const Bucket& Bucket::operator=(const char* str) {
    if (this->_str == str) {
        return *this;
    }
    
    _len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) _len++;

    _str = new char[_len + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++)
        _str[i] = str[i];
    _str[_len] = '\0';

    return *this;
}

const bool Bucket::operator==(const char* str) {
    int comp = strcmp(this->_str, str);
    if (comp == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bucket& myBucket) {
    os << myBucket._str;
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Bucket& myBucket) {
    static char buffer[40];
    is >> buffer;

    int len = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        myBucket._str[i] = buffer[i];
        len++;
    }
    myBucket._str[len++] = '\0';

    return is;
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    Bucket b1("Hello, "); // This is deleted by the destructor
    Bucket b2(b1); // This is deleted by the destructor
    cout << b1 << b2 << endl; 
    b2 = "Dear ";  // Also works fine
    Bucket b3;
    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    cin >> b3; // Can't assign the _len attribute
    cout << b2 + b3 << ",";  // not destroyed
    Bucket b4(" Please write this sentence after pressing enter:\n");
    b2 = "We believe that ";
    cout << b4 + b2 << b1 << "and " << "Goodbye "  // not destroyed
        << (b1 == "Goodbye " ? "is " : "is not ") << "the same word!\n" <<
        endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Be sure to also read Sam's advice. But at a glance, I see a destructor and no copy operators, so you should also read the C++-specific page [What is the Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: What is String?

Comment: Fyi, `if (_len > 0) delete[] _str;` that precondition was not present in the default ctor when you allocated a sequence of zero-length and stashed the resulting pointer; it should not conditioned in the destructor either. I concur with the Ro3 references, btw. Important.

Comment: Also , don't call new[] with zero size to initialize pointer .Yes, it's defined and result is a non-null pointer , dereferencing it invokes UB though but guards against it do not exist. It also must be deleted.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't just use `std::string` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a lot of issues with how your `Bucket` code is implemented:

- the 2nd parameter of `operator>>` needs to be a reference to a **non-const** object, otherwise the operator can't modify the object while reading data from the `istream`.
- lack of a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, and preferably also a move constructor and move assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).
- the default constructor is allocating memory with `new[]`, but since `_len` is 0, the destructor won't free that memory.  You need to remove the check for `_len > 0` when calling `delete[]`.
- the default constructor is not null-terminating the allocated array, as the other constructors are doing.
- `operator+` is returning a new `Bucket` object *by value* (as it should be), so marking that object as `const` is redundant.
- Same with the `bool` that `operator==` returns.  However, the `operator` itself should be marked as `const`, since it doesn't modify the `Bucket` object it is called on.
- both `operator+` are using `strcat()` incorrectly.  The `Bucket` overload is modifying the contents of `this->str_`, which it should not be doing, and worse `this->_str` hasn't been reallocated anyway to increase its capacity to append the contents of `myBucket._str`.  The `char*` overload is making a similar mistake with `tempBucket.str_`. You need to allocate a whole new `char[]` array for each `tempBucket`.
- the `Bucket` overload of `operator+` is declaring `tempBucket` as `String` instead of as `Bucket`.
- `operator=` is returning the modified `Bucket` object *by reference* (as it should be), but that object should not be maarked as `const`.
- `Bucket` does not expose a way to access its `_str` member from outside code, so there is no way that the `if (this->_str == str)` check in `operator==` will ever be true.
- `operator=` is not `delete[]`'ing the old `_str` memory before replacing it with a new `char[]`.
- `operator>>` is not performing any bounds checking on the `buffer` it reads in. And it is not re-allocating `myBucket._str` to fit the contents of `buffer`.  And, it is counting the null terminator in `_len`, which none of the other class methods do.

With all of that said, try something more like this instead:

```
class Bucket
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bucket& rhs);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Bucket& rhs);
public:
    Bucket(size_t len = 0);
    Bucket(const Bucket& src);
    Bucket(Bucket&& src);
    Bucket(const char* str);
    Bucket(const char* str, size_t len);
    ~Bucket();

    Bucket operator+(const Bucket& rhs) const;
    Bucket operator+(const char* str) const;

    /*
    Bucket& operator=(const Bucket& rhs);
    Bucket& operator=(Bucket&& rhs);
    Bucket& operator=(const char* str);
    */
    Bucket& operator=(Bucket rhs);

    bool operator==(const Bucket& rhs) const;
    bool operator==(const char* rhs) const;

private:
    char* _str;
    size_t _len;

    void swap(Bucket &other);
    bool equals(const char* str, size_t len) const;
    Bucket concat(const char* str, size_t len) const;
};
```

```
static size_t my_strlen(const char* str) {
    const char* start = str;
    if (str) while (*str != '\0') ++str;
    return (str - start);
}

Bucket::Bucket(size_t len) {
    _len = len;
    if (len > 0) {
        _str = new char[len + 1];
        _str[len] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        _str = nullptr;
    }
}

Bucket::Bucket(const Bucket& src)
    : Bucket(src._str, src._len) { }

Bucket::Bucket(Bucket&& src) : Bucket(0) {
    src.swap(*this);
}

Bucket::Bucket(const char* str)
    : Bucket(str, my_strlen(str)) { }
    
Bucket::Bucket(const char* str, size_t len) : Bucket(len) {
    if (str && len > 0) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            _str[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
}

Bucket::~Bucket() {
    delete[] _str;
}

void Bucket::swap(Bucket &other) {
    char *ptmp = _str;
    _str = other._str;
    other._str = ptmp;

    size_t itmp = _len;
    _len = other._len;
    other._len = itmp;
}

bool Bucket::equals(const char* str, size_t len) const {
    if (this->_len != len) return false;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (this->_str[i] != str[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Bucket Bucket::concat(const char* str, size_t len) const {
    Bucket tempBucket(this->_len + len);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->_len; ++i) {
        tempBucket._str[i] = this->_str[i];
    }
    for(size_t i = this->_len, j = 0; j < len; ++i, ++j) {
        tempBucket._str[i] = str[j];
    }
    return tempBucket;
}

Bucket Bucket::operator+(const Bucket& rhs) const {
    return concat(rhs._str, rhs._len);
}

Bucket Bucket::operator+(const char* rhs) const {
    return concat(rhs, my_strlen(rhs));
}

/*
Bucket& Bucket::operator=(const Bucket& rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        Bucket(rhs).swap(*this);
    }
    return *this;
}

Bucket& Bucket::operator=(Bucket&& rhs) {
    Bucket(std::move(rhs)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

Bucket& Bucket::operator=(const char* rhs) {
    Bucket(rhs).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
*/

Bucket& Bucket::operator=(Bucket rhs) {
    rhs.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

bool Bucket::operator==(const Bucket& rhs) const {
    return equals(rhs._str, rhs._len);
}

bool Bucket::operator==(const char* rhs) const {
    return equals(rhs._str, my_strlen(rhs));
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bucket& rhs) {
    os.write(rhs._str, rhs._len);
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Bucket& rhs) {
    /*
    string buffer;
    is >> buffer;
    rhs = buffer.c_str();
    return is;
    */
    char buffer[40];
    if (!is.get(buffer, 40)) buffer[0] = '\0';
    rhs = buffer;
    return is;
}
```

---

That being said, if you can use standard C++ functionalities, such as  `std::string`, then the code becomes a whole lot simpler:

```
#include <string>

class Bucket
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bucket& rhs);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Bucket& rhs);
public:
    Bucket() = default;
    Bucket(const Bucket& src) = default;
    Bucket(Bucket&& src) = default;
    ~Bucket() = default;

    Bucket(const std::string& str);

    Bucket operator+(const Bucket& rhs) const;

    Bucket& operator=(const Bucket& rhs) = default;
    Bucket& operator=(Bucket&& rhs) = default;

    bool operator==(const Bucket& rhs) const;

private:
    std::string _str;
};
```

```
Bucket::Bucket(const std::string str) : _str(str) { }

Bucket Bucket::operator+(const Bucket& rhs) const {
    return Bucket(this->_str + rhs._str);
}

bool Bucket::operator==(const Bucket& rhs) const {
    return (this->_str == rhs._str);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bucket& rhs) {
    os.write << rhs._str;
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Bucket& rhs) {
    is >> rhs._str;
    return is;
}
```